# boost char_ptr_holder instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, boost, constructor, initialization

I'm trying to instantiate the following class defined in the boost libraries

defined in boost/interprocess/detail/segment_manager_helper.hpp

```
 template<class CharType>
 class char_ptr_holder
 {
   public:
    char_ptr_holder(const CharType *name)
    : m_name(name)
   {}

  char_ptr_holder(const anonymous_instance_t *)
     : m_name(static_cast<CharType*>(0))
  {}

  char_ptr_holder(const unique_instance_t *)
    : m_name(reinterpret_cast<CharType*>(-1))
  {}

  operator const CharType *()
  {  return m_name;  }

  private:
   const CharType *m_name;
};
```

But I'm not able to. I'm confused because m_name is a pointer, but is being "constructed" in the initialization list with an argument of CharType *.

help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
char_ptr_holder<char> value("Hello!");
```

Comment: ah right .. i templated it with <char*> and was wondering ... thank you